# Is it possible to add an SSL certificate to an existing deployment?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, kubectl

I am wondering if it is possible to add an SSL cert to an existing kubernetes deployment... I am running a deployment with an ELB service and would like to add another domain (customer domain) which has HTTPS (other than my amazon issued cert) which I have already attached using the "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert" annotation.

Comment: Documentation suggests `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert` takes certificate ARN. Can't you create a new certificate with all required domains and switch to its ARN?

Comment: technically, yes.... however assuming our service has hundreds of users it would be quite time consuming and inefficient to create a new ARN and re-release every deployment when one user adds a new domain

Comment: Sounds like ELB/ALB is the wrong solution for you. It only [supports](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/) up to 25 certificates.

Comment: I would recommend to use "traefik" and "let's encrypt" that way you don't have to take care of every and each certificate everytime a user adds a service/new domain